# JQuery Validation: Validating hidden fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Since the release of the JQuery Validation Plugin version `1.9.0`, hidden fields have been automatically omitted from validation checks [[source](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/)].

According to the [release notes](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/), the way to get around this is by setting `ignore: []` in the validation function.

Using version `1.10.0`, I am unable to get this to work for input fields that are hidden using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.

My validation is done using classes (eg, `class="required"`) and the validation function is fairly basic:

**JQuery**

```
$("form").validate({
    ignore: [],  
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( $('#error-message') )
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        //do something 
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fbCVY/**

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: When I run the jsfiddle in Firefox 17.0.1, the `submit` button always shows "no error" in the console - even after removing the CSS that hides the input fields.  Am I missing something, or is the jsfiddle not really set up to fail the validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to provide both a unique `id` and a unique `name` attribute for each of the `input` tags so that the validation plugin can find the fields and can tell them apart.  The two "hidden" fields are not failing validation because the first field on the form passes, and that result is being used for the other two fields.

Comment: +1 awesome - seems a bit strange that they are reliant on ids. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: it is just name the inputs need

Answer (score 2):

Try with rules:

```
$("form").validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        name: ["aa", "ee"]
    },  
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( $('#error-message') )
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        //do something 
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbCVY/13/)

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks - it is not actually the rules I need, I was omitting the `name` attribute which was causing the issue (so your jsfiddle works, but it is because you added the `name` attribute to the input rather than needing the rules): http://jsfiddle.net/fbCVY/14/